# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm making a plug-in where I can shorten the title of each entry in a forum index if it is too long. However, that is much harder than I expected.

Everything goes fine except when I get to the part where you actually have to print the items onto the DOM.

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is my code with a bunch of notes I left to show you how it works.

```
var minimize = function() {
    $('.segment').each(function(){
        var title_box = $(this).children('.title');
        // Selects the container of the title.
        var title = $(this).children('.title').text().trim();
        // Takes the child title of the each .segment class and selects its innards.
        console.log(title);
        var res = title.split("");
        // Splits the text into an array.
        console.log(res);
        var fragment = [];
        // initializing the empty array
        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            fragment.push(res[x]);
            console.log(fragment);
            // Loops through to make sure it's not more than 5 characters long
        };
        var final = fragment.join("");
        // Joins the broken up string together.
        title_box.empty();
        final.appendTo(title_box);
    });
};
```

What do you think I did wrong? And if there's any other ways for me to make this code more efficient, then please don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: Where do you get the error? Which line?

Comment: variable "final" is a string which joined by "" from fragment, but not a jQuery object.
should be $(final).appendTo(title_box);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right here you define `fragment` as an array:

```
var fragment = [];
```

You then populate it and do this:

```
var final = fragment.join("");
```

Read the docs on [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to understand what that function does. In short, it joins your array together into a `string`

So now when you do this:

```
final.appendTo(title_box);
```

You get your `TypeError` because string doesn't have an `appendTo` method

What you probably wanted was a jquery object to call `appendTo` on.

Perhaps you meant:

```
title_box.text(final);
```

Comment: Man oh man. The details. Thank you very much. This was a big learning experience. I'll mark you as the right answer very shortly.